# Translate form data in another language

Tags: php, yii, internationalization, yii-extensions

I want to translate form data in another language on submit in Yii and save the translated data in database with language name.How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use [Google Translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/)

or [translate](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/translate/) extentsion for Yii